# Unexpected behaviour when using 'append' of Python list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to understand this behaviour of **python lists**.

When I'm appending an empty list to another list, I expect the new list to contain an empty list only. But I am failing to understand why its adding unexpected values.

```
main = [ [1,2,3], [4,5], [6] ]

l1 = []
l2 = []

for i in main:
    
    for j in i:
        l1.append(j)
    
    # reseting value of l1 to empty list
    l1 = []
    
    # expected behaviour: an empty list will be added!
    l2.append(l1)

print(l2)
```

I **expect** this code to print

```
> [[], [], []]
```

But its **giving** me:

```
> [[4, 5], [6], []]
```

Could someone please explain how this is happening ?

Comment: On the first iteration of the outer loop, you append an empty list, `li`.  Then on the next iteration, *your inner loop appends a bunch of values to that list*. So consider `a = []; b = []; a.append(b); b.append(42); print(a)`

Answer (score 1):

`l1 = []` doesn't mean "clear this list". It means "create a new empty list and make the `l1` name refer to that list". Whatever object `l1` referred to before is unmodified by this operation.

Also, `l2.append(l1)` doesn't mean "append a copy of `l1` to `l2`" or "append this variable to `l2`". It means "append *this particular list* to `l2`". `l2` receives a reference to the original list, not a new list, and modifications to the original list will be visible through `l2`. (It receives a reference to the *list*, not to the `l1` variable - rebinding `l1` to a new list will not affect `l2`.)

---

At the end of the first iteration of your outer loop, you append an empty list to `l2`. The next iteration then appends a bunch of stuff to *that list*, then rebinds `l1` to a new empty list, leaving a bunch of elements in the old list. The same happens on the next and final iteration of the outer loop.

If you want to clear a list, use

```
l1.clear()
```

or

```
del l1[:]
```

instead of `l1 = []`.

Also, if you want to create a (shallow) copy of a list, you can use `l1[:]`. For example, appending a copy of `l1` to `l2`:

```
l2.append(l1[:])`
```

If you change your code to clear `l1`, but don't append copies to `l2`, then `l2` will contain 3 references to a single list. That's rarely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is appending to the list instead of clearing try this instead:

```
l1.clear()
```

instead of

```
l1 = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `l2` list will be changed during next iteration. Maybe this code will give you more explanations:

```
for i in main:

    for j in i:
        l1.append(j)
    print(id(l1),id(l2))
    if l2:
        print(id(l2[0]))
    # reseting value of l1 to empty list
    l1 = []

    # expected behaviour: an empty list will be added!
    l2.append(l1)
```

Check that `l2[0]` and `l1` ids are equal.

Answer (score -2):

The python lists are mutable and append method changes them 'in-place'.
Assignment actually makes variable to point into another place in the memory. After the first exit from the innermost loop you reset l1 to point on to an empty list so `l2 set to [[]]`. Next, inside the inner loop, you modify that empty list in place. Next `l1 = []` creates an empty list and point 'l1' to it. The procedure repeats.
You can add debug statements inside the loop `print(l2)` and see yourself.

Due to complexity of handling mutable data and the immutable data are gaining momentum. You will have no such issues with immutable type like tuple.

PS. While list are sometimes confusing, in many cases lists are more convenient than tuples, just be extremely careful with them. I recommend to do more list exercise to get better understanding and what side it might cause, for example

https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/thinkcspy/Lists/ListsareMutable.html

Another python gotcha with mutable data is the default function argument value can be modified inside the function.